# Generic type creator

Tags: java, generics, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Generics: Cannot cast List<SubClass> to List<SuperClass>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246137/java-generics-cannot-cast-listsubclass-to-listsuperclass)

I want to create function on some base class, that create it inheritance classes.

I have try this:

```
class BaseFormat
{
    // Some variables

    public BaseFormat(string txt)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<T extends BaseFormat> getTextFormat(String[] txt)
    {
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++)
        {
            list.add(new T(txt[i])); // ERROR
        }
        return list;
    }
}

class FooFormat extends BaseFormat
{
    // Some variables

    public FooFormat (string txt)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

And this:

```
class BaseFormat
{
    // Some variables

    public BaseFormat(string txt)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public static ArrayList<BaseFormat> getTextFormat(String[] txt)
    {
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++)
        {
            list.add(new BaseFormat(txt[i]));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

But when  I try to cast the array I receive an error. This is my code:

```
String[] txts = ...; // Some texts
ArrayList<FooFormat> list = (ArrayList<FooFormat>) BaseFormat.getTextFormat(txts); // Casting ERROR
```

So how can I do it, but still keep it generic?

Comment: What do you want to do with `ArrayList<FooFormat> list`?

Comment: You cannot create an instance of a generic type. Some options might be to have subclasses register with the base class or provide an instance of `Class<?>` from which you could use reflection to call a constructor.

Comment: FooFormat is-a BaseFormat but not vice-versa.

Comment: You cannot cast from `List<X>` to `List<Y>` which of course makes sense because your code is creating an instance of `BaseFormat`, how could that be treated as a `FooFormat`?

Comment: I have methods in FooFormat, and I know that strings should be `FooFormat`

Comment: I thought that if FooFormat extends BaseFormat it shold work

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the [PECS acronym](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to pass the type in as a parameter to the static method, and then probably use reflection to invoke `Class.newInstance`.  Type erasure means you will not have a concrete type T after compilation, so that is why you can't compile `new T(...)`

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
  ArrayList<BaseFormat> list = (ArrayList<BaseFormat>) BaseFormat.getTextFormat(txts);
```

Then on iterating you can down cast the items to FooFormat with check of instanceOf operator

Comment: But I cant cast BaseFormat to FooFormat

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something as follows

```
class BaseFormat { }

class FooFormat extends BaseFormat { }

class FormatUtils {
    public static <T extends BaseFormat> List<T> getTextFormat(String[] txt, Class<T> clazz) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        //... 
                T t = clazz.newInstance(); //create instance using reflection
                //...
        return list;
    }
}
```

And do

```
List<FooFormat> list = FormatUtils.getTextFormat(new String[]{}, FooFormat.class);
```

Comment: I cant create T object in `getTextFormat` function.

Comment: Can you add Class<T> type param to the method?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are mixing generics, which allow dynamic typing, with inheritance, which allows overriding methods.  What you really want is to separate creating the wrapped string from creating the list.

```
class BaseFormat
{
  // derived classes override this method to provide their own implementations
  public abstract BaseFormat wrapText(String[] txt);

  public ArrayList<? extends BaseFormat> getTextFormat(String[] txt)
  {
    ArrayList<? extends BaseFormat> list = new ArrayList<BaseFormat>();
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++)
    {
        list.add(wrapText(txt);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<? extends BaseFormat>();` makes errors.
And still, I cant cast from `BaseFormat` to `FooFormat`

Comment: Fixed the constructor.

If you are using polymorhism, you don't need to know its a FooFormat. The methods you call on the object will perform the FooFormat version, not the BaseFormat version.

Comment: I see, but I need it static. Can I do it with static way?

Comment: So, why does it need to be static? If it's static, how to you plan on creating the new, derived classes?

Comment: So, basically, I think your design is broken. You should not *need* static methods.

Comment: This method create instance of Format classes. I cant just call for it constructor.
This method act like factory.