# How to create an Object to an in interface which is having generics

Tags: java

I'm facing below difficulty while instantiating an interface.

```
public interface HostSender < T extends Serializable, R extends Serializable> {
}

public class MySender implements  HostSender< MessageRequest, MessageResponse> {  
}
```

Problem:

```
HostSender< Serializable, Serializable> messageSender= null;
```

Can somebody tell me how to create object for above statement? I try with new operator in following ways but it doesn't work.

```
messageSender = new MySender<MessageRequest, MessageResponse> ();
messageSender = new MySender ();
```

Comment: `<T extends Serializable, T extends Serializable>` - is that a typo? Two generic type parameters shouldn't have the same name.

Comment: Try `HostSender<? extends Serializable, ? extends Serializable> messageSender`,  `HostSender<?, ?> messageSender` or `HostSender< MessageRequest, MessageResponse> messageSender`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Generics: Cannot cast List<SubClass> to List<SuperClass>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246137/java-generics-cannot-cast-listsubclass-to-listsuperclass)

Comment: Sorry , the exact interface code is  
public interface HostSender< T extends Serializable, R extends Serializable >{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class "MySender" is not generic. Therefore, you must use this :

```
HostSender< ? extends Serializable, ? extends Serializable> messageSender= null;
messageSender = new MySender();
```

Comment: It will issue a compiler warning.