# Cast in generics

Tags: java, generics

I have this code:

```
MessageConsumer<String> handler = consumer.handler(handleBusRequest());
MessageConsumer<Object> handler2 = (MessageConsumer<String>) handler;
```

But cast it is not allowed. How should I do it?

Comment: You shouldn't do that, for [the same reasons that the compiler doesn't allow it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po). If you know what you're doing, then you [can still cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246137/java-generics-cannot-cast-listsubclass-to-listsuperclass)

Comment: You can do List<? extends String> handler2 = handler;