# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<X509Certificate> to Collection<Certificate>

Tags: java, tomcat9, java-security

I am trying to implement Tomcat-9's source code.

I have one line of code as follows:

```
Collection<Certificate> chain = new ArrayList<>(certificateFile.getCertificates());
        if (certificate.getCertificateChainFile() != null) {
            PEMFile certificateChainFile = new PEMFile(certificate.getCertificateChainFile());
            chain.addAll(certificateChainFile.getCertificates());
        }
```

The code is compiling fine in eclipse but when I try to build it though build.xml using ant builder. I get an error saying:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to Collection

Why is this behaviour observed? Any idea?

Comment: There are many classes called `Collection`. Do you use `import java.util.Collection;`? Ditto for the other types: which `Certficate` are you using?

Comment: Why you don't use `List` instead of `Collection`, the List interface extends the Collection. So you will be ok in any case. e.g. `List<Certificate>`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize, that you are referring to [this code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/45514a31b96c242e772f768cba1574152741ffc6/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLUtilBase.java#L319). What do you mean by _"implement"_? If you copied the lines into your own file, you might have used the wrong import statements.

Comment: By implement I mean I take their source code and implement my own mwthods for getting-seeting password and protocols, etc

Comment: Although the error message is mangled, this is YA case of container covariance; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082044/most-efficient-way-to-cast-listsubclass-to-listbaseclass https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246137/java-generics-cannot-cast-listsubclass-to-listsuperclass https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Import and everything was correct. I modified `Collection<Certificate>` to `Collection<X509Certificate>` and everything looks good.