# Compile time error when overriding generic method with More Specific return type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to change return type of implementation with more specific implementation. What am i missing here?

Interface Method

```
public Collection<Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>>> entrySet();
```

Implementing Class Method

```
public Collection<Entry<K, List<V>>> entrySet(){
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to the semantics of the `? extends` wildcard. The second generic parameter of `Entry` is covariant, so `Entry<K, List<V>>` is indeed a subtype of `Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>>`.

However, there is no wildcard for the generic type parameter of `Collection`, so it is *invariant*. If we let `Dog` be `Entry<K, List<V>>` and let `Animal` be `Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>>`, you will see that this is the classic situation of

> Why isn't `ArrayList<Dog>` a subtype of `Collection<Animal>`?

[Classic Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246137/java-generics-cannot-cast-listsubclass-to-listsuperclass)

`Collection<Entry<K, List<V>>>` simply is not a more specific type than `Collection<Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>>>`. They are unrelated.

It will work if you declared it as:

```
Collection<? extends Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>>> getEntries();
```

Note the extra `? extends` in the generic type parameter of `Collection`.